# need to check select fields for selected value that have dynamically assigned id's

Tags: javascript, jquery

The numeric value in the id is dynamically assigned ranging from [0 - 5]. I'm wondering, using `jquery or js`, how would I dynamically check each select element so I can test if the user has selected a value or not? I only ask because the `Required` attribute does not work with `ie < 10`

html

```
<select name="responses[4].score.id" id="responses[4].score.id">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="41">5: Excellent</option>
    <option value="31">4: Above average</option>
    <option value="21">3: Average</option>
    <option value="11">2: Below average</option>
    <option value="1">1: Unsatisfactory</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Why do you have an id that looks like that? It's far from optimal.

Comment: Why would you need IDs here?

Comment: I'm only contributing to this project, didn't write it. I believe, the name/id is written that way because that matches the properties for the response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($('select').filter('[value=""]').length) {
   // at least one SELECT is not selected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One method:

```
for(i=5;i<0;i++){
   if($('#responses['+i+'].score.id').val()==""){
      //not selected here
   }
   else; //value= more than ""
}
```

another method:

```
$('select[id=^"response"]').foreach(){

}
```

There are many ways of achieving it through selectors. It's whatever selector you feel is best or takes less work.

javascript would be a little different to jQuery.